# how to integrate Spring and GWT from 2 different projects

Tags: eclipse, spring, gwt

I am tying to integrate a gwt project with my already running spring project.
i am using eclispe, and i have a Spring MVC application that receives JSON requests.

i am using the built in Tomcat to run my MVC application.

now i would like to create a new GWT project and have it communicate with my spring project with JSON.

i understand that they need to run on the same ip and port so i would not have to make cross site communication.

if i try to run my GWT application as run-as->Web application (which is the normal way for the project) on the same port as the Tomcat server i get an error that the address is already in use (which makes sense)

i tried creating a new dynamic web project and make it look the same as the GWT project. even though i am able to run the application, nothing happens, and the "entry point" is not run (i am not getting any errors or anything) it just runs the default HTML welcome file and thats it. with out any GWT.

what am i doing wrong, i am surly misunderstanding something about how all this should work.

can anyone help me out please.

Comment: did you add the gwt-html file (ModuleName.html) to the web.xml's welcome file list?

Comment: in which project? i have to point out again that each of the projects alone works fine... if i run the GWT project everything works, if i run the Spring project, it works. but they are on different ports. so nothing would work that way between them.

Comment: In the GWT project. Maybe you forgot to copy the content of the web.xml from the 'old' project... Regarding the communication: you need to expose the function you need from the spring project (with rpc or as a ejb service) or you integrate it into the web (as a jar or module dependency)

Comment: here exactly is the problem, there is no "Old project". I would like to run them separately.
Is that even possible? or do i have to "copy" my spring implementation into the GWT project?

Comment: either integrate the spring project as a module (jar) into the web or call a service (ejb, webservice) of the spring project from the client-side of the gwt project. If both will be running on the same server anyways I recommend the first as it is simpler

Comment: the spring project is a dynamic web project by itself... is that the wrong way to go as well? should i make it a "regular" java project (with public static void main?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select that you are running on an external server:

[image]

Comment: that doesn't work. i enter the http://localhost for the ip and 8080 which is the tomcat running port... and i get that the ip address is already taken

Comment: Make sure you have unchecked the 'run built in server' option

Comment: i have managed to get this to work. but i get an error from the browser saying Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode.

Comment: That happens if you stop development mode in Eclipse. Restart it in eclipse and refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

That is a question that can't just be answered with yes or no. It all depends on your overall architecture and what you are trying to achieve.

As I said, if it is both the same application I'd recommend to integrate the Spring project into the web project. (and if that's the case, the spring project does not need to be a web project)

If the spring project is its own application and maybe running on a different server, keep them separated. Extend the spring project so it offers the functionality (via ejb or webservice) the gwt-web project needs.

Nevertheless, I recommend you do some reading about how Java EE applications should be designed and what the different tiers (client, server/service, business, etc) are for. Oracle/Sun offers some good articles. For example: http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications_2e/ or http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaay.html#bnabb.